# Macbook white screen of death not able to boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, crash

My macbook 2011 17.5" won't start.

I tried all options listed here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255 on how to boot with different keycodes. Only single user mode seems to work everything else ends in white screen a few seconds after the apple logo. I can choose the startup disk and tried booting from a backup but that also resulted in whitescreen.

Is there anything else I can try?
Maybe reset the system completely somehow?

Comment: really? All options. I was just about to ask u to boot into verbose mode

Comment: Is anything plugged into the MacBook other than the power adapter?

Comment: No I unplugged everything.

Comment: I tried verbose mode. It didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Does the Mac boot to recovery mode or internet recovery mode?

Comment: No. That too ends in white screen.

Comment: Have you tried [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: using only D results in whitescreen. starting with Alt + D works but unfortunately it doesn't detect any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac shows a white screen in recovery mode or internet recovery then there is a hardware issue on your mac.

My recommendation is to either contact Apple Support for an appointment or set up an appointment yourself via https://getsupport.apple.com/.

This could be a hard drive or display issue. If not then you are looking at a logic board replacement.

*If you have a time machine backup or a separate backup of your things
elsewhere then you should be fine, if not then you'll want to get the hard drive* (***if that is the issue***) *taken out and then purchase a new one, so you can take your current hard drive to the nearest data recovery center nearby you.*